# Installing mod_wsgi on WAMP server running on Windows 7

Tags: windows-7, apache-http-server, python, wamp

I downloaded mod_wsgi from the [following location](http://code.google.com/p/modwsgi/wiki/DownloadTheSoftware?tm=2) for apache 2.2 and python 2.7. (I'm trying to get django to run on my computer).

Whenever I add the following line:

```
LoadModule wsgi_module modules/mod_wsgi.so
```

Apache fails to start up. Can anyone tell me what the issue might be?

Answer (score 0):

I had this same problem.

Make sure to download the 32bit module if running 32 bit and 64 if running 64. IE: Python, Apache, and your module should all be either 32 or 64. Also ensure that it is the right module for your version of python.

I found this site to be useful for fining all modules.

http://www.lfd.uci.edu/~gohlke/pythonlibs/#mod_wsgi